# Jmeter results - advice on perfomance testing

Tags: javascript, performance, http, jmeter, performance-testing

We have executed the Performance tests. Started with 25 Users and we see application crashes and application does not respond for 15 users.
Error percentage gradually increased from 0 to 100 for 15 users in 2 to 4 minutes. Below are the errors and snaps for performance tests.

Errors:
•   Server side errors
•   The resource cannot be found.
•   HTTP 404 errors.

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

Can you give some pointers to improve the performance?

Comment: Caching, Load data on demand

Comment: already its cached in couch base

Answer (score 0):

Well, there could be many reasons for the failure. Did you keep JMeter and the server in the same machine?

If yes, probably that is the reason for failures as both JMeter & Server consume resources.

If not, then check the following settings.

Following are the `Checklist/Suggestions/Pointers`:

**Client Side:** Simulate the anticipated load - neither less not more (There may a chance of wrong test design/scripting which resulted in more/less than the anticipated load)

1. Ramp-Up: Check how 25 threads are launched. There should be enough ramp-up time (say 25 threads in 2 minutes) unless you are conducting Stree/Spike test.
2. User Think Time: Check whether you added any timer b/w the transactions or not. If not, you are generating the more load than the anticipated. Add Timer b/w transactions to replicate real-time scenario.
3. Pacing: Check whether you are giving any time b/s each iteration. It not, It fastens the execution speed.
4. Misplaced timers (scope): Check whether your timer is applicable to all the samplers/transactions.
5. Cache configuration: Configure cache for static resources using HTTP Cache Manager, so that from second iteration JMeter uses its cache instead of requesting the server. This decision must be taken only if the server is allowing the client to cache the resources (check Cache-control and other related headers). Otherwise, this configuration can be ignored.
6. Parallel requests: If you are using `Parallel Downloads` field in HTTP Sampler, don't keep it more than 6 (modern browsers use multi-threading to download resources in parallel).

Above factors, if misconfigured, can result in unwanted load.

**Server Side:**

1. Scarcity of resources in Server machines: Use `nmon for Linux, PerfMon for Windows`. Analyze the results and find which resource is causing the trouble i.e., CPU, Memory, Network, HardDisk I/O. (Most common reason for server crash)
2. Misconfiguration of the server: Check for maxThreads, minThreads, maxConnections, Keep-Alive timeout, connection timeout etc. and tweak as per the needs.

**Possible solution:**

If resources are the bottleneck and you are generating the anticipated load, then either you have to `scale in` (add resource which is the bottleneck to the existing machine) or `scale out` (deploy the app in more server machines)

Comment: thanks for the answer, need some time to digest the answer , will come back :)